# Android two spinners showing wrong

Tags: android, spinner

I have created two spinners dynamically, but one is showing little bellow the middle, how to put it in the same "line"?

http://oi60.tinypic.com/jt8kqt.jpg

```
    typySp2 = new MySpinner(context.getApplicationContext(), db.getTableTypy());
    typySp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {


            String text = typySp2.getSelectedItem().toString();

            ArrayAdapter<String> categoriesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext().getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, db.getTableOperace(text));

            operaceSp.setAdapter(categoriesAdapter);


        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {


        }       

    });
    editaceOperaceLl.addView(typySp2);

    operaceSp = new MySpinner(context.getApplicationContext(), db.getTableOperace(typ));
    editaceOperaceLl.addView(operaceSp);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure but i think you should do that in the layout XML and play with the paddings

edit:

this is just an example, the weight is important

```
<TableRow 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:weightSum="100"
       >
       <EditText 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="50"
           />
       <Button 
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="30"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Button1"
           />

   </TableRow>
```

you can also do it in java with this :

```
x.weight = number;
```

Comment: I dont know why it is showing like this, because is the same code for both, but one is showing good and one wrong

Comment: can you post a screenshot maybe?

Comment: you have to give it a weight to both, i will edit my answer in a 1sec

Comment: I also had to set LayoutParams to Match parent, thanks for help ;)